Vertex Paint problem
Well, right now i’m having a problem with Vertex Paint. I was trying to give some shades to a texture, but the Vertex Paint doesn’t show up. It’s visible on object mode, but not in my texture. Can someone tell me i’m doing something wrong or it’s a Blender problem? Thanks!

Are you meaning to use vertex color attribute as replacement for the material color or image texture? You can add an attribute node to your shader and reference your color attribute name to plug that vertex color into the color input of your principled bsdf.

Hello could you please show a screenshot of your Shader Editor?

Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add images of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

During vertex paint, colors are stored into an" Attribute".
You can access this information in the shader editor with Menu > Add > Input > Color Attribute, selecting the Attribute you painted on (they can be more than one), and plugging its Color output into the Base Color input of a shader.

